# Phonegap - use iframe as the app

Tags: ios, iframe, cordova

So, i made a responsive website i would like to include that inside an `iframe` and push it to `phonegap` so that i can easily create a mobile application without coding a new.

What i'm wondering about is:

1. How to embed the website from the url? (best practice)
2. Apple will reject my app if i'll use an iframe ? (if yes why)
3. Which other tips to follow for achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need an iframe, the config.xml have a parameter for the starting url, it can be an url on a server
2. Most likely, yes, apple reject apps that are just a web wrapper. You can try to use a iOS like UI and some native functionalities.
3. I think if you follow 1 and 2 you can achieve this, but it's always better to use local html, css and javascript and use ajax calls to communicate with the server

Comment: thank you, i can't understand why apple could reject the app, if the webapp points to a mobile website wich is being developed to run as ios app too :( anyway thank you man i think i'm gonna accept your answer

Comment: Well, I think nobody understands apple, but these are their rules.